# Оптимизация обхода по многомерному массиву

Tags: php, рекурсия, foreach, nested-sets

Есть многомерный массив с неизвестной вложенностью. Нужно его обойти до определенного уровня(на данный момент 5) и записать данные в свой массив. Обход написал при помощи пятиуровневого foreach, но выглядит как-то не красиво:

```
  $hierarchy = [];

    // Build data tree for five referrals levels
    // First level
    foreach ($manager->getReferrals($user) as $fistKey => $firstLvl) {
        $hierarchy[$fistKey] = [
            'key' => $firstLvl['user']['id'],
            'title' => $firstLvl['user']['username'],
        ];

        // Second level
        foreach ($firstLvl['__children'] as $secondKey => $secondLvl) {
            $hierarchy[$fistKey]['children'][$secondKey] = [
                'key' => $secondLvl['user']['id'],
                'title' => $secondLvl['user']['username'],
            ];

            // Third level
            foreach ($secondLvl['__children'] as $thirdKey => $thirdLvl) {
                $hierarchy[$fistKey]['children'][$secondKey]['children'][$thirdKey] = [
                    'key' => $thirdLvl['user']['id'],
                    'title' => $thirdLvl['user']['username'],
                ];

                // Fourth level
                foreach ($thirdLvl['__children'] as $fourthKey => $fourthLvl) {
                    $hierarchy[$fistKey]['children'][$secondKey]['children'][$thirdKey]['children'][$fourthKey] = [
                        'key' => $fourthLvl['user']['id'],
                        'title' => $fourthLvl['user']['username'],
                    ];

                    // Fifth level
                    foreach ($fourthLvl['__children'] as $fiveKey => $fiveLvl) {
                        $hierarchy[$fistKey]['children'][$secondKey]['children'][$thirdKey]['children'][$fourthKey]['children'][$fiveKey] = [
                            'key' => $fiveLvl['user']['id'],
                            'title' => $fiveLvl['user']['username']
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Как можно это оптимизировать? Нужна рекурсия или можно и при помощи циклов решить эту задачу?

Comment: если в вопросе будет пример исходного массива и ожидаемый массив результат - будет проще

Comment: Учитывая, что на всех уровнях поля называются одинаково, можно сделать рекурсивную функцию, которой передавать указатель на текущую ветвь и количество оставшихся уровней, она обходит свой уровень и вызывает себя же для каждой ветви, уменьшив на 1 кол-во уровенй